# want to know how to get the syllables in telugu script

Tags: python

i am working on telugu script whose unicode range is 0C01-0C7F
can u explain how to find out the syllables in that

(Update copying from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654680) question )

I am able to categorize chars but in telugu script one syllable may contain one or more chars, and when retrieving the chars from the file the syllable is divided and not able to combine them, so please help me out if any one know about telugu script text categorization

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak telugu (sorry!), but I do understand that it's a syllabic-based language where syllables are composed of vowels (“achchu”s) and consonants (“hallu”s). So, as [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu_language) explains, you end up with "sixty symbols, of which 16 are vowels, three vowel modifiers, and forty-one consonants".  [This page](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/teluguchart.html) shows the Unicode correspondence: vowels are 0C05 to 0C14 (and also 0C60 and 0C61, "vocalic" RR and LL); consonants are 0C15 to 0C39; the other codes are the many "signs, punctuations, digits" and so on.

A complete table of possible syllables is at [this PDF](http://www3.aa.tufs.ac.jp/i-moji/tenji/nakama/tlg_syl.pdf), but I confess the script is throwing me off as I have trouble telling what is what.  If you speak telugu, or have easy access to people who do, you'd be in a better place to tell how to carve syllables out of a stream of telugu characters than I am.  Python doesn't have much to do with it -- it's just one programming language out of many that may let you implement whatever **algorithm** you need for the syllabic determination, but it definitely has no such algorithm built-in!-)

Answer (score 2):

In Telugu, the syllables are formed in several ways

- V (at the beginning of the word in the independent form)
- C + V (consonant + vowel in the dependent form)
- C + C + V  (consonant + consonant + vowel)
- C + C + C + V consonant + consonant + vowel)

If you are using english script to transliterate into telugu (like google transliteration tool), it is possible that many english characters form just one syllable.

Consider "stree" (type this in google transliteration tool) and this forms just one syllable in Telugu. You can analyze that Telugu string at http://rishida.net/tools/analysestring/index.php?list=స్త్  to understand how the telugu syllables are formed.

You have two options two solve this problem

[1] Figure out the code point sequence if your input is in Telugu script. And group the code point sequences based on when a vowel is ending and a new syllalbe is starting.

[2] If your input is in English that maps to Telugu characters, then you need to figure out when to break the sequence into multiple syllables.